# Stored procedures with joined data in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, join

We currently have a system with quite large database and stored procedures are used both for CUD and querying. DataSets are used to retrieve the results from the SP querys.

Now we are looking into developing another project against the same database using Entity Framework. When querying the database, the stored procedures often perform a lot of joins to gather some fields not in the target table, but data from the joined tables that is needed by the client in some way. When using DataSets, all the fields returned by the SP was included in the DataTable. So the DataTable doesn't actually match the target database table.

What is the correct way of handling this scenario in EF? When creating my model, the entities are mapped to each table which as mentioned above only sometimes matches the result of the SP. Can I add the "additional" fields of the SP query result to the entity class as properties and have them filled by the query but with these properties being excluded when it comes to CUD on the specific entity type? Seems like the EF-way, if queried through LINQ to Entities and not SPs, would be to have entity instances with relational properties to the joined entities so that using those "additional" properties would be done by navigating the relational properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an arbitrary *complex type* (just a class that's generated for you, to match the columns and datatypes returned by the stored procedure) as the return type for your stored procedure in Entity Framework (as of version 4 and newer) - no problem here.

See [Stored Procedures in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) for a great explanation of all things related to using stored procedures in Entity Framework.

Comment: But complex types aren't able to interact with EF as trackable entities, right? I need to be able so perform CUD operations on the entities, I just need them to carry some extra information that isn't tracked.

Comment: @nobba: a complex type is a "container" class to hold your data returned from the stored procedure. They are in themselves no entities per se - but they can definitely *interact* with existing EF entities! Why do you think they can't ??

Comment: Sorry, it seems I mixed up complex types with something else. Would the best way be to map the "extra properties" that originates from other tables to a complex type and then add that to the main entity? Because I don't want to end up with only complex types.

Comment: @nobba: if you have a stored procedure that returns those extra values, then EF will create a complex type that contains all your entity properties plus your extra fields. You can use something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to easily map those complex types to the actual entity types you already have (to save yourself a lot of boring and mindless left-right-assignment statements)

Comment: Yes, I use Auto-Mapper in some other scenarios so that is a possibility. Still I'm not sure if you mean that the complex types will work just as normal entity types when it comes to CUD operations? If the SP returns a complex type, what happens if I delete it and save changes on the context?

Comment: @nobba: nothing will happen - since those complex types are **NOT** mapped to a table! They're just the output "container" of a stored procedure that you imported into Entity Framework. If you need to delete an entity based on a value contained in that complex type, you'd have to use the PK value of that entity to actually delete the real entity (which *is* mapped to a table) from your context.

Comment: Well, that is what I meant in my first comment with "complex types aren't able to interact with EF as trackable entities". Seems that I will have to do a lot of mapping then. Isn't it possible to do something like what I wrote in the question, where I have the main entity and then the complex type holds the additional fields? I guess that the problem is the SP and its return "type" and that it can't map partially to an entity and partially to the complex type?